# How do I allow a text input to a TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm working on a custom text classification model in TensorFlow, and would now like to set it up with TensorFlow serving for production deployment. The model predicts on the basis of a text embedding that's computed via a separate model, and that model requires the raw text to be encoded as a vector.

I have this working in a somewhat disjointed way right now, where one service does all the text preprocessing and then computes the embedding, which is then sent to the text classifier as the embedded text vector. It would be nice if we could bundle this all into one TensorFlow serving model, especially the initial text preprocessing step.

And that's where I'm stuck. How do you construct a Tensor (or other TensorFlow primitive) that is a raw text input? And do you need to do anything special to earmark the lookup table for the token-vector component mapping so that it gets saved out as part of the model bundle?

For reference, here's a rough approximation of what I have now:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 510], name='input')

# lots of steps omitted for brevity/clarity

outputs = tf.linalg.matmul(outputs, terminal_layer, transpose_b=True, name='output')

sess = tf.Session()
tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess,
                           'model.pb',
                           inputs={'input': input}, outputs={'output': outputs})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be relatively straightforward, thanks to the `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable` that's available as part of the TensorFlow standard library.

My model is using a bag of words approach, rather than preserving order, though that would be a pretty simple change to the code.

Assuming you have a list object that encodes your vocabulary (which I've called `vocab`) and a matrix of corresponding term/token embeddings you want to use (which I've called `raw_term_embeddings`, since I'm coercing that into a Tensor), the code will look something like this:

```
initalizer = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(vocab, np.arange(len(vocab)))
lut = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(initalizer, 1) # the one here is the out of vocab size
lut.initializer.run(session=sess) # pushes the LUT onto the session

input = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None, None], name='input')

ones_at = lut.lookup(input)
encoded_text = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(ones_at, tf.dtypes.cast(lut.size(), np.int32)), axis=0, keepdims=True)

# I didn't build an embedding for the out of vocabulary token
term_embeddings = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.vstack([raw_term_embeddings]), dtype=tf.float32)
embedded_text = tf.linalg.matmul(encoded_text, term_embeddings)

# then use embedded_text for the remainder of the model
```

The one small trick is also making sure to pass `legacy_init_op=tf.tables_initializer()` to the save function to hint TensorFlow Serving to initialize the lookup table for the text encoding when the model is loaded.

Comment: I'd like to save the staticvocabulary object , preferably in a tensor flow model object. And use that model in a rest service, could you point to any resource to convert vocabulary type to a TF model ?